# Replace value from CSV with Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have to replace values in a large CSV file and decided for Python as programming language I want to use.

The value I need to change is the first on each line in my comma separated CSV:

```
ToReplace, a1, a2, ..., aN
1, ab, cd, ..., xy
80, ka, kl, ..., df
```

It's always a number, the amount if digits isn't fixed, though.

I've got two ideas at the moment: Process the data line by line and ...

1. Use a regular expression to match the number
2. Use the CSV component to parse the line

As I'm very new to Python there are some questions that came to mind:

- Considering the file's size (> 50GB; ~ 10 million lines), which method is faster?
- How to implement it without wasting lots of resources?

Comment: Aside: 50 GB is too large a file to keep in a flat format like a CSV.  Either switch to a database or at least split the files to something more manageable (500 100MB files, e.g.)

Comment: That's exactly why I need to process the file so I can put it in the DB in a fast & clean manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the first column that always contains a number then you could use a string method instead of a more general `csv` module, to avoid parsing the whole line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    with open('50gb_file', 'rb') as file, open('output', 'wb') as output_file:
        for line in file:
            number, sep, rest = line.partition(b',')
            try:
                number = int(number)*2 #XXX replace number here
            except ValueError:
                pass # don't replace the number
            else:
                line = bytes(number) + sep + rest
            output_file.write(line)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second argument to Python's `split` method in order to get just the first match, replace that with whatever you want, then join back into a single string, like this:

```
import logging

with open('example.csv', 'rb') as infile, \
        open('result.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for line in in file:
        try:
            number, rest = line.split(',', 1)
            number = 'blob'
            outfile.write(','.join([number, rest]))
        except ValueError:
            logging.error('The following line had no separator: %s', line)
```

For 10 million rows, on 2 cores at 2.4 GHz and 8 Gb RAM, I get the following times:

```
$ time python example.py

real    0m20.771s
user    0m20.336s
sys 0m0.369s
```

Comment: `number, rest = line.split(',', 1)` fails if a line has no comma in it. Use compatible file modes for both files (either both binary or both text).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : you are right, I edited my answer to improve on both aspects. However, I preferred to log the error because "Errors should never pass silently." ;)